# Facebook comment box show different content with and without "http://www..." prefix. (in joomla)

Tags: facebook, joomla, facebook-comments

My exact problem is that I receive different comment content for these urls:
http://kornyezetvedelem.co.hu/index.php/187-a-kozteri-futoversenyt-is-megadoztatjak
http://www.kornyezetvedelem.co.hu/index.php/187-a-kozteri-futoversenyt-is-megadoztatjak

How could I fix this?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having Facebook likes accumulate over https:// and http://](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10543089/having-facebook-likes-accumulate-over-https-and-http)

Comment: (same answer - you need both URLs to have an og:url meta tag pointing to the canonical URL, the one you want to receive the likes and shares)

Answer (score -1):

It's normal. Always use domain with www prefix